# What's going to change in the kernel in Natty?

Tags: 11.04, kernel

Does anyone know what changes are coming?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The short answer is: *Lots*.

### Official:

As a kernel is released, though not before, all of the changes are written up in the Changelog: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/

You'll notice they are published for each minor release. They contain absolutely everything, and are almost impossible to read, if you're not into all things kernel. :-)

### Not official:

I usually read [The H](http://www.h-online.com/)'s summary of changes to the kernel. They've summarised all of the changes that you'll see in Natty quite well. Be warned, there are multiple pages behind each of the links:

- 2.6.36

  - [Coming in 2.6.36 (Part 1) - Graphics](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-36-Part-1-Graphics-1075471.html)
  - [Coming in 2.6.36 (Part 2)](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-36-Part-2-File-systems-networking-and-storage-1081745.html)
  - [Coming in 2.6.36 (Part 3) - Architecture & Infrastructure](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-36-Part-3-Architecture-Infrastructure-1100492.html)
  - [Coming in 2.6.36 (Part 4) - Drivers](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-36-Part-4-Drivers-1100878.html)
- 2.6.37

  - [Coming in 2.6.37 (Part 1) - Graphics](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-37-Part-1-Graphics-1144218.html)
  - [Coming in 2.6.37 (Part 2) - File systems](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-37-Part-2-File-systems-1148305.html)
  - [Coming in 2.6.37 (Part 3) - Network and storage hardware](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-37-Part-3-Network-and-storage-hardware-1153025.html)
  - [Coming in 2.6.37 (Part 4) – Architecture and infrastructure code](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-37-Part-4-Architecture-and-infrastructure-code-1156965.html?anchor=power)
  - [Coming in 2.6.37 (Part 5) - Drivers](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-37-Part-5-Drivers-1158991.html)
- 2.6.38

  - [Coming in 2.6.38 (Part 1) – Graphics](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-38-Part-1-Graphics-1176900.html)
  - [Coming in 2.6.38 (Part 2) – File systems](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-38-Part-2-File-systems-1192694.html)
  - [Coming in 2.6.38 (Part 3) – Network drivers and infrastructure](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-38-Part-3-Network-drivers-and-infrastructure-1197480.html)
  - [Coming in 2.6.38 (Part 4) - Storage](http://www.h-online.com/open/features/Kernel-Log-Coming-in-2-6-38-Part-4-Storage-1199926.html)

and [everything else](http://www.h-online.com/search/?rm=search;perpage=5999;filter_t1=1;q=kernel-log) as it's published

---

A (comparatively minimalistic) summary of the changes regarding *Ubuntu in particular* can be found on the Wiki pages for the pre-releases:

- [Natty Narwhal Alpha 1](http://www.ubuntu.com/testing/natty/alpha1)
- [Natty Narwhal Alpha 2](http://www.ubuntu.com/testing/natty/alpha2)
- [Natty Narwhal Alpha 3](http://www.ubuntu.com/testing/natty/alpha3)

Comment: Almost exactly what I was going to write tomorrow morning if nobody else had. I love the H-Online digests. +1

Comment: Your two Alpha links are going to the same page (alpha2).